# Writing to smart contract as owner on BSCScan Smart Contract with Gnosis Safe wallet gnosis-safe

Tags: gnosis-safe

We have a smart contract on BSC and we were using Ledger for our owner wallet, to write to the smart contract on BSCscan.
We are undergoing a Certik audit, and Certik asked us to move the owner wallet to a multisig wallet such as Gnosis.

Our main concern is that - if we move the owner wallet to Gnosis, will we be able to write to our smart contract as _owner using BSCscan.com's contract write page?
This is really important for us because if we're unable to do so, then we effectively will lose all access to the smart contract.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

When speaking about a multisig wallet, in order to execute a method on a smart contract, a new proposal needs to be created and signed by N out of M signers.
Having this in mind, you'll be able to perform any function call on your smart contract (that's marked as [onlyRole](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/access-control) for example) only through a dedicated proposal.

The simplest solution I recommend is using [OpenZeppelin Defender](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IOescPDrF7Y&ab_channel=OpenZeppelin) to create a Gnosis Safe and manage proposals. Using their platform you can create a new proposal (either by UI or programmatically) and invite all the signers to approve it.